# How to check if authenticated user is handler of REST resourece

Tags: rest, authentication, yii2

I've developing a REST service on Yii2 and Angular 2 client. Using Bearer JWT authentication.
For example there is a uri: http://127.0.0.1/v1/accounts/123456/meters, which should return all user's meters by account, which he own.

Applied router rule:

```
'<accountId:\w+>/<action:[\w-]+>' => '<action>',
```

Controllers has following behaviors:

```
'authenticator' => [
    'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
    'except' => ['options']
],
'access' => [
    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
    'rules' => [
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'actions' => ['meters'],
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ]
    ]
]
```

Action AccountController::actionMeters looks:

```
public function actionMeters($accountId)
{
    // Call MS SQL procedure
    $meters = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("EXEC [getMetersByAccountId] :accountId")->bindValue(':accountId', $accountId)->queryAll()
    return $meters;
}
```

But in this way authenticated user can get (if modify GET accountId parameter) meters, which belongs to another user.

I have a user_account table in database, which link users and accounts, but I don't know in which place of application should I perform a checking properly.

How to make a check if authenticated user has an access to this resource by specified accountId parameter?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution to determine matchCallback in access rule. Now it's look:

```
[
    'allow' => true,
    'actions' => ['meters'],
    'roles' => ['@'],
    'matchCallback' => function() {
        return Yii::$app->user->identity->user->hasAccount(Yii::$app->request->get('accountId'));
    }
],
```

And define hasAccount method in User model:

```
public function hasAccount($accountId) {
    return $this->hasOne(UserAccount::className(), ['user_id' => 'id'])->where(['account_id' => $accountId])->exists();
}
```

It's work correct. Is it a proper solution?